# why does alternate current attract and direct current repel

Tags: electromagnetism

Does AC current attract and DC repel our body? If the potential difference remains same will still AC and DC will give us same type of electric shock?

Comment: _Does AC current attract and DC repel our body?_ Do you mean if we'll be thrown away if we touch a wire? _If the potential difference remains same will still AC and DC will give us same type of electric shock?_ If you're asking about the medical effects, then clearly no.

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118456/12613

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about human physiology

Comment: Stop reposting questions just because they get downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 0):

> **why does alternate current attract and direct current repel**

It doesn't.

> **Does AC current attract and DC repel our body?**

No. Any kind of electrical current will tend to cause muscles to contract. Depending on which muscles are in the electrical path, this might cause your hand to tightly grasp a conductor or it might cause your arm and/or leg muscles to spasm, throwing you across a room.

A difference between AC and DC is that changing currents in AC create a magnetic field that can induce currents in *nearby* conductors. This is how mains transformers work. However it usually requires good conductors (your body really isn't that good a conductor), very close distances and other factors that don't usually apply to human bodies.

Any effect would be too small for you to notice directly.

> **If the potential difference remains same will still AC and DC will give us same type of electric shock?**

This is really a Biology or Health question.

I believe AC can be more harmful to muscles at typical frequencies used in household supply as it can trigger fibrillation.

> The let-go threshold in AC a current of 3 to 22 mA is required against 15 to 88 of DC current.

See

- [AC and DC shock comparison](http://www.brighthubengineering.com/power-plants/89792-ac-and-dc-shock-comparison/)
- [Physiological effects of electricity](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_3/2.html)